# Trying to build a tic tac toe without any state (in pure fp style)

Tags: swing, user-interface, clojure, stateless

I am learning Clojure and trying to implement a simple tic-tac-toe (or morpion). But i am working hard in order to avoid any ref/atom/agent ...

I know I could do it easily in a console application, as it would not be event-driven, so that   I would exactly know when to pass in a new board value. I mean

- my board would be a vector of vectors ([[:circle 0 :cross][:any :circle :empty][:cross :none :none]] where only :circle and :cross values matter)
- I would have a simple text-based method which takes a board and return a string

But, whenever I want to implement a graphical Panel, I wonder how can I do the same thing. For example :

- I am creating an instance of javax.swing.JPanel (please don't care about the other methods that are used here) :

  ```
  (defn make-board-panel
  "Builds the board JPanel, whose state is given by board argument,
  and turn-piece argument (must be either :circle or :cross, I mean the next
  value to set in the board)."
  [board turn-piece]
  {:pre ['morpion.core/is-board? board, 'morpion.core/is-a-player-piece? turn-piece]}
    (proxy [JPanel MouseListener] []
      (paintComponent [g]
          (proxy-super paintComponent g)
          (paint-board-lines g)
          (paint-board board g)
      )
      (mouseClicked [e]
          (if (and (abs-coord-in-cell? (.getX e)) (abs-coord-in-cell? (.getY e)))
              (let [cell-x (abs-coord-to-rel (.getX e))
                      cell-y (abs-coord-to-rel (.getY e))]
                  ;; Here I compute the new board value
              )  
              nil ;; Here I wish I could return the new board value to the caller of make-board-panel, but this seems impossible !
          ) 
      )
      (mouseEntered [e])
      (mouseExited [e])
      (mousePressed [e])
      (mouseReleased [e])
     )
  )
  ```
- But it seems that there are no way for me to fetch the new value of the board, from the mouseClicked event of the Panel : unless I introduce a state variable.

So is there a workaround  :

Sources for my complete project :

- [Morpion Core](http://pastebin.com/d0Uepqkv)
- [Morpion Graphic](http://pastebin.com/D88ke1ev).

(I've tried to improve thanks to Igrapenthin comment, but I am still failing.)

Comment: You could pass a callback-function as an additional parameter that will be called from inside the MouseListener with the new board value.

Comment: Thanks for your idea : I am trying it right now. I did not think about this way (Clojure beginner :) )

Comment: Are you sure you're using your preconditions right? It looks like all it's doing now is checking of the provided values are non-nil, but that you actually want to check that `board` is a board and `turn-piece` is a piece.

Comment: Why ? Did I forgot parenthesis or something similar ?

Comment: You can't avoid state unless you want to replace your panel by a new one after each turn.

Comment: Yes, that what I planned to do. But for now, I still have some errors to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn make-board-panel
 [board turn-piece output-fn]
 (proxy [JPanel MouseListener] []
   ;; ...
   (mouseClicked [e]
     (when (and (abs-coord-in-cell? (.getX e)) 
           (abs-coord-in-cell? (.getY e)))
       (let [cell-x (abs-coord-to-rel (.getX e))
             cell-y (abs-coord-to-rel (.getY e))]
          ;; Here I compute the new board value
          (output-fn new-board-value))))
    ;; ...
    ))
```

Comment: Yes, I've written something like that, but I am still facing a strange ArityException in my code (it does not point me to the problem, but it just says ArityException in : Symbol)

Comment: your error is certainly due to the quote (') before morpion.core/play-board

Comment: Thanks, I quoted 'morpion.core/play-board because I thought I could fix the namespace problem that way. But it didn't. So I must try with require/use instead.

Comment: If the issue is one of recursive require (both namespaces require the other), either make a third that both can require, or use `resolve` to look up the namespace and function at runtime.